# Function in R with multiple parentheses

Tags: r, function, parentheses

Have You ever come upon function in R, that has multiple parentheses, i.e. function()()?

I would be pleased with syntax for creation of such function.

Thanks!

Comment: The function can return other function, so you can evaluate its result. 
Specifically you can think of it as `f <- g(); f()` is the same as `g()()`

Comment: The `scales` package has very accessible (i.e. friendly/easy to grok) example. This is one of them: https://github.com/hadley/scales/blob/646b6a433e6f7106bed4173569898fac409d22b5/R/formatter.r

Answer (score 1):

This can work if a function returns a function.  Here is an example.

```
Power = function(p) { function(x) x^p }
Power(3)(2)
[1] 8
```

Comment: or `f <- function() { g }; g <- function() "hello"; f()()`